# How can I get a wxPython frame with FancyText and no border (wx.BORDER_NONE)?

Tags: python, wxpython, border, noborder

I would like to build a wxPython window without borders (i.e., `style = wx.BORDER_NONE`) and use fancytext (`wx.lib.fancytext`) inside this window. Note that I am very new to wxPython and my question may sound stupid. (this is actually my first attempt of using wxPython).

I figured that I will need to use a `panel` in my `frame` when using fancytext as one needs the `OnPaint` method for setting the fanciness for the text. However, it seems to be impossible to use `panels` (or even `sizers`) with `style = wx.BORDER_NONE`.

This is what I would like, but without the window borders and stuff:

```
import  wx
import  wx.lib.fancytext as fancytext

test_str2 = '<font family="swiss" color="dark green" size="40">big green text</font>'

class FancyText(wx.Panel):
    """display fancytext on a panel"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        """generate the fancytext on a paint dc canvas"""
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        fancytext.RenderToDC(test_str2, dc, 0, 20)


app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title='wxPython fancy text', size=(500, 250))
frame.Centre()
FancyText(frame)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

(This examples uses code found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/128350/643697#post643697) and from the wxPython demo)

If one changes the line initializing the window to

```
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title='wxPython fancy text', size=(500, 250), style = wx.BORDER_NONE)
```

the fancytext disappears.

Is there any way I can use fancytext on a window without borders (`style = wx.BORDER_NONE`)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the panel is not resizing to the size of the frame. You need to use a sizer, like this:

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(FancyText(frame), 1, wx.EXPAND)
frame.SetSizer(sizer)
frame.Layout()
```